# Signing out of rails app when signed out of facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

Haven't seen this question asked, but if something similar, please point me that way!

I learned the fb login from the railscast pro eps (http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api?view=asciicast) but can't get the logout to work properly when the user signs out of their facebook. I made the app "live" so sandbox mode shouldn't be an issue.

On the JS side, I have

```
  if $('#sign_out').length > 0
    Fb.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      window.location = $('#sign_out').attr("href") if !response.authResponse
```

And on the menu navbar, I have

```
 <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out" %></li>
```

Seems to make sense to me... I don't use JS much so maybe I'm missing something simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being something really stupid

Fb needed to be capitalized

```
FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
```